# Reorder using Join in Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want my XElements in document order.
Can I reorder my `xpathGroups` using Join like in this example?

```
XDocument message_doc = XDocument.Load(message);

var xpathGroups =
    from e in contextErrors
    group e by SelectElement(message_doc, e.XPath) into g
    select new
    {
        Element = g.Key,
        ErrorItems = g,
    };

var documentOrderedGroups =
    from elem in message_doc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf()
    join e in xpathGroups on elem equals e.Element
    select e;
```

Message:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <aa>
            <aaa>9999</aaa>
        </aa>
        <aa>
            <aaa>8888</aaa>
        </aa>
    </a>
    <b>
        <bb>
            <bbb>7777</bbb>
        </bb>
    </b>
    <c>
        <cc>
            <ccc>6666</ccc>
        </cc>
    </c>
</root>
```

Input data:

```
/root/c[1]/cc[1]/ccc[1]
/root/a[1]/aa[2]/aaa[1]
/root/b[1]/bb[1]/bbb[1]
/root/a[1]/aa[1]/aaa[1]
```

Expected result:

```
/root/a[1]/aa[1]/aaa[1]
/root/a[1]/aa[2]/aaa[1]
/root/b[1]/bb[1]/bbb[1]
/root/c[1]/cc[1]/ccc[1]
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample XML, examples of `e.XPath`, and your expected result?

Comment: It is actually really simple. XPath selects always a single XElement. The List of XPath is not sorted in any way. I want these single XElement, selected by the XPath, to be in document order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original queries work, and the result is an object with the element and its relevant XPath query in document order. However, the result conflicts with the comment you made that you only want the elements in document order.

**Elements and XPath:** if you want both the element and its XPath then the join will remain as part of the query but I would replace the grouping with a projection into an anonymous type.

```
var xpathElements = contextErrors.Select(e => new
                    {
                        Element = message_doc.XPathSelectElement(e.XPath),
                        XPath = e.XPath
                    });
var ordered =  from e in message_doc.Descendants()
               join o in xpathElements on e equals o.Element
               select o;
```

**Elements only:** if you only want the elements to be in document order, the following approach would work as well.

```
var xpathElements = contextErrors.Select(e => message_doc.XPathSelectElement(e.XPath));
var ordered = message_doc.Descendants()
                         .Where(e => xpathElements.Any(o => e == o));
```

In both examples I've used the [`XPathSelectElement method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355.aspx) to take the place of your 
`SelectElement` method, which I gather has the same purpose.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. The projection I used is ok for me and is just what I want. I only wanted to know if it is possible to use a join to get the result in document order. You answered that question. Btw is the where in the ordered query redundant?

Comment: XPathSelectElement is called in my SelectElement method.

Comment: @frast you're right, the `where` is redundant. I updated to remove it. I think the join approach is fine.